# add large string milliseconds with number milliseconds

Tags: javascript

when I store Date.now() in the database as a bigint (postgresql), making a recall for the value returns a string instead of a number (due to javascript inability to handle large numbers).

Is there a way I can utilize the javascript `Date` library to compare the string of milliseconds with the Date.now() milliseconds?

Something like this...

```
const oldDate = "1590367617261"; // returned as string from database
const timout = 5 * 1000; // ms

console.log(oldDate + timout);
```

Expected Output:

`1590367622261`

Actual Output:

`15903676172615000`

Comment: const oldDate = 1590367617261;

Comment: Postgre has a data type called `time` for those use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parse** oldDate to **Int** before adding it

```
const oldDate = "1590367617261";
const timout = 5 * 1000; // ms

console.log(parseInt(oldDate)+ timout);
```

Adding **string to int** will result in **string concatenation**.
Adding **int to int** will result in **addition operation**.

Comment: This works, but I'm a little confused why. The value of a max int is 2147483647. The number is 1590367617261 (bigger than max int). Does the `parseInt` somehow see it is bigger and provide some alternative value to run with math expressions?

Comment: and more importantly, is this safe to use when comparing datetime values with timouts?

Answer (score 0):

Type the value of oldDate  without ""

```
const oldDate = 1590367617261;
const timeout = 5 * 1000; // ms
console.log(oldDate + timeout);
```